# Implementing a custom view in android

Tags: java, android

I have been working with Android for a while now , but recently something new came up . 
I am supposed to make a Calendar. There is a default CalendarView View however it is drastically different from the Calendar that my client wants .

Now I embarked upon the "Create your custom view " tutorials on the internet.

I found out either I could extend something that existed , or extend View .

I extended View . My motive was to start with the basics that is draw the grid of buttons that would represent days of the month, upon clicking which the user would be navigated to a different page .

Here is where I reached a deadend. I know that onDraw is used to create the visual of a view. However we have to use the Canvas class. How can I include a android.widget.Button, as a part of layout in the onDraw method ?

Or have I completely gone rouge and am following an incorrect way ?

Please aid me. Thanks

Comment: you can add buttons or textview or any widget you want to the cusotmview using `addView(button)`.

Comment: instead of adding a button, you should draw a button(rectangle or any suitable shape) there and check whether the touch event was inside the bounds of that button.. This would have been my approach for a better user experience

Comment: @Raghunandan, unfortunately , canvas doesn't contain a method called addView .

Comment: the viewgroup does have addView. you can extend a view group such as  `RelativeLayout` and addview to the same. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: you can manually draw your view to canvas..but it does not make sense, Android does it for you..

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), in case of the Calendar, I would advice you to subclass [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).
It might be easier to just draw your gird of days to the canvas manually.

GridView will be easier to start with, but canvas will offer you much richer possibilities.

If you choose GridView, you should create an adapter where will be one a day.
If you choose Canvas, you should basically draw your items in two nested for cycles, the outer for rows the inner for columns. You can draw text, shapes, basically just everything directly to the canvas.
On the other hand going with standard android views will allow you to integrate touch events or for example animations in much easier way. Doing such things only with canvas is much more complicated.

Comment: thanks . Yes I think if i go with canvas , i will have to find out manually which area of the grid did the user press, to correctly identify the relevant date that was inside that box . I would have to keep track of the dates , and where they are in the box . It sounds doable and complicated . 

GridView on the other hand yes . I think I should go with this . Do I even need to subclass the GridView ? . I think I can natively place a button in a cell of the grid ? .